# Gatsbyjs static query wont load

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'm running into an issue where I've created a non page component with a StaticQuery that is pulling information with a set up like this.

```
const BestSellers = () => (
  <div>
    <StaticQuery
      query={bestSellerQuery}
      render={data => (
        <div>
          {data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.map(({ node }) => (
            <Card className="m-2 index-card" key={node.id}>
              <Link to={node.fields.slug}>
                <GatsbyImage
                  className="card-img-top"
                  image={node.frontmatter.image}
                  alt={node.frontmatter.description}
                />
              </Link>
              <hr />
              <CardBody>
                <Link to={node.fields.slug}>
                  <CardTitle className="h4 text-light text-wrap">
                    {node.frontmatter.title}
                  </CardTitle>
                </Link>
                <CardSubtitle>{node.frontmatter.description}</CardSubtitle>
                {/* <CardSubtitle>{node.excerpt}</CardSubtitle>   */}
                <CardSubtitle className="float-left mt-5">
                  Price: ${node.frontmatter.price}
                </CardSubtitle>
                <CardSubtitle>
                  <Badge color="danger float-right mt-5">
                    {node.frontmatter.tag}
                  </Badge>
                </CardSubtitle>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    />
  </div>
);

const bestSellerQuery = graphql`
  query bestSellerQuery {
    allMarkdownRemark(
      filter: { frontmatter: { tag: { eq: "popular" }}}
      sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }
      limit: 2
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          frontmatter {
            title
            description
            price
            tag
            image {
              childImageSharp {
                gatsbyImageData(
                  layout: CONSTRAINED
                  height: 600
                  placeholder: BLURRED
                  formats: [AUTO, JPG]
                  transformOptions: { fit: COVER, cropFocus: ATTENTION }
                )
              }
            }
          }
          fields {
            slug
          }
          excerpt
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

export default BestSellers;
```

What I'm doing is my pages are being created programmatically from a Markdown file once it is clicked on so I'm trying to import this into the template that i use to create pages and it just shows loading(static query) I've tried using this same query in pages that do and don't have a page query on them and it results in the same as using this in the template component that I'm trying to use it in.

Comment: Is the query working in the `localhost:8000/___graphql`? Can you print the result of the loop like `{data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.map(({ node }) => { console.log("node", node); return <Card className="m-2 index-card" key={node.id}>`?

Comment: Well this comment made me start breaking things down to figure out where the issue was which lead me to fixing the issue so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It was the issues in the graphql query which was being used more specifically the line
filter: { frontmatter: { tag: { eq: "popular" }}}
the issue was the "popular" in the MD file is in caps so by changing it to "POPULAR" that solved it....